# Case and Where condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Following is my sql code. I want all the ids with description that have create time or update time between 25-Aug to 31-Aug.

Currently, if an id has create time between 25-Aug to 31-Aug, though the update time is in Sep, the sql is returning the record for the update time.

Ideally it should only return the records that have create or update times between 25-Aug to 31-Aug. Why is my case ignoring the condition for update time?

```
select t1.id, t1.desc,
Case
WHEN t1.create_time IS NOT NULL
THEN t1.create_time
WHEN t2.update_time IS NOT NULL
THEN t2.update_time
END AS "TimeStamp"
from t1, t2
where t1.id=t2.id(+)
AND ( t1.create_time BETWEEN TO_DATE ('25-AUG-2016 00:00:00',
                                   'dd-mon-yyyy HH24:Mi:SS')
                   AND TO_DATE ('31-AUG-2016 23:59:59',
                                'dd-mon-yyyy HH24:Mi:SS')
       OR (  t2.update_time
                   BETWEEN TO_DATE ('25-AUG-2016 00:00:00',
                                    'dd-mon-yyyy HH24:Mi:SS')
                   AND TO_DATE ('31-AUG-2016 23:59:59',
                                'dd-mon-yyyy HH24:Mi:SS')
                )
            )
```

Comment: Switch to modern outer join syntax. (I don't understand that old Oracle syntax.) Which table do create_time and update_time belong to?

Comment: sorry, I have updated the table info.

Comment: instead of case you may use coalesce()

Comment: but I need both the values, I need create time for sure and update time when it falls in the time range. does coalesce bring both?

Comment: Have two coalesce's. (But your case expression returns only one value...)

Comment: Coalesce() is a short-hand case and can take multiple parameters. It will only return NULL if all parameters are NULL and will return the first parameter value which is not NULL. Right now, you are only getting one of the fields anyway.

Comment: No, I am getting both the values, however the update time doesnt fall in the time range in my where condition, that is the issue I am facing.

Comment: if you need both create-date and updated-date, just select those columns without checking the NOT NULL and CASE.

Comment: but I want both of them to appear in the same column - TimeStamp. when the id has both create time and update time, it has to be in 2 rows.

Comment: You can not get 2 values in one column-place. its either created or updated-dt only you may get. if you want both columns it should be 2 column output, unless you concatenate.

Comment: if you want 2 rows of result then you may need to run 2 sql with union/union all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query conditions for `create_time` and `update_time` combined by `OR`. When we combine two condition by `OR`, if one of condition is `TRUE` then result also will be `TRUE`.  As result, in your query if `create_time`  falls within the range, then not metter `update_time`  falls within the range or not.

You can use subqueries to filter tables before you join them

```
select t1_1.id, t1_1.desc,
CASE
WHEN t1_1.create_time IS NOT NULL
THEN t1_1.create_time
WHEN t2_1.update_time IS NOT NULL
THEN t2_1.update_time
END AS "TimeStamp"
from (select * from t1 
       where t1.create_time BETWEEN TO_DATE ('25-AUG-2016 00:00:00',
                                             'dd-mon-yyyy HH24:Mi:SS')
                                AND TO_DATE ('31-AUG-2016 23:59:59',
                                             'dd-mon-yyyy HH24:Mi:SS')) t1_1, 
      (select * from t2 
         where t2.update_time BETWEEN TO_DATE ('25-AUG-2016 00:00:00',
                                             'dd-mon-yyyy HH24:Mi:SS')
                                  AND TO_DATE ('31-AUG-2016 23:59:59',
                                             'dd-mon-yyyy HH24:Mi:SS')) t2_1
where t1_1.id_=t2_1.id_(+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.desc,
t1.create_time  'TimeStamp'
from t1 
where
trunc(t1.create_time) BETWEEN TO_DATE ('25-AUG-2016','DD-MON-YYYY')
                   AND TO_DATE ('31-AUG-2016','DD-MON-YYYY')
union all
SELECT t1.id, t1.desc,
t1.update_time 'TimeStamp'
from t1 
where
(  trunc(t1.update_time)
                   BETWEEN TO_DATE ('25-AUG-2016','DD-MON-YYYY')
                   AND TO_DATE ('31-AUG-2016','DD-MON-YYYY')
                )
```